# blender player extended monitor problem

Tags: command-line

I have an iMac and two mac Cinema displays connected using thunderbolt.
The Cinema displays are setup as extended (each 2048*1152 giving 4096*1152 overall).

The iMac is setup below the Left hand extended monitor ( I have previously had it set as mirror to this monitor but same situation happens).

I have set the Left Hand Monitor to Primary.

Now I can use  { blenderplayer -w 4096 1152 0 4096 file.blend } from terminal, and get a game window spanning both Cinema displays, so far so good.

However I am struggling using the -f option to give fullscreen rather than window, I would assume that I should use   { blenderplayer -f 4096 1152 file.blend } to span the monitors but this only results in the 2048*1152 of the Left hand monitor being used.

Am I doing something incorrect or is it a blender or OSX feature that will not allow a full screen request to overlap physical screens.

Thanks